# i using Yoast SEO plugin to make site map, but post-sitemap.xml error

Tags: wordpress, seo

[image]

i using wordpress vesion 4.3, when used Yoast SEO only page post-sitemap.xml error.
how i can fix it?
thanks for wathcing.

Comment: Please share error messages in text and not only a picture. If you only use a picture the search engines cannot pick up and help others. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plugin doesn't escape Vietnamese symbols. So try to rename image file that causes this error.

Answer (score 1):

XML has a special set of characters that cannot be used in normal XML strings. 
Here '&' is a special character.

These characters are:

```
& - &amp;
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
" - &quot;
' - &#39;
```

For example, the following XML string is invalid:

```
<Organization>IBM & Microsoft</Organization>
```

Whereas the following is valid XML:

```
<Organization>IBM &amp; Microsoft</Organization>
```

—Note that we have replaced `'&'` with `'&amp;'` in the second XML string which makes it valid.